# Is it possible to run each layer in a cnn parallely in either caffe or tensorflow?

Tags: optimization, tensorflow, parallel-processing, caffe, conv-neural-network

I want to run each layer of a trained CNN in parallel to reduce the computation time during forward propagation ( Basically I want to run the CNN for a real time application involving a camera without affecting the FPS too much ). I will keep an input queue and an output queue for each layer. Each layer can process a blob from input layer and dump it in the output layer ( This can logically be done in parallel ). Output queue for each layer will work as the Input Queue for the following layer. And then I will collect all the outputs from the output queue ( its going to be a binary label ) of the final layer and process them. So my question is that is it possible to run each layer of a CNN in parallel in either Caffe or Tensorflow to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Tensorflow you can specify "device placement", so for each operation or group of operations in the graph you can say on which GPU to run it, for example, if you have several GPUs. See [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu) for sample code on how to place operations on GPUs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about TF.
About caffe - this sounds like a bad idea. Putting queues and sync mechanism between the layers will only slow you down (especially if you run on GPU and sync through CPU constructs). Caffe is design to perform the forward pass sequentially and to do it FAST. Why do you expect parallelism to help you run it faster?

Comment: Suppose I have 10 images for classification using a CNN. Now using forward propagation in Caffe, each of my Images (Except the first one ) has to wait for the image in the queue before it to  go through the whole cnn pipeline which is a waste of time. As soon as the first image passes through the first layer the second image should enter it and so on.

Comment: I know the fastest way would be to launch each pipeline in parallel but that would consume too much of the resources ( Basically the multiple of weights in the CNN layers )

Comment: @AyushPandey if you have resources enough for `K` frames, you are better off running them as a batch of size `K`.